# Unity crashing Mac or running extremely slow on Mac Catalina

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a project with `Unity 2021.3.4f1` on a 2015 MacBook air (Catalina) and have been having problems with it. Quite often it causes my whole laptop to shut down and reboot with the message "Your computer restarted because of a problem".

The rest of the time is running extremely slowly to the point where it is unusable.

I have not done much in the project yet, but can already see this problem has gotten worse since I have added more updates. Please does anyone know why this could be happening and what to do about it?

Would downgrading/upgrading Unity solve this problem? From what I have read online, this seems to be a common issue with Mac users but I am yet to find a solution.

Thanks

Comment: Did you check the load on your machine?  Maybe your CPU/RAM setup isn't sufficient for game development.

Comment: I agree with @MaartenDev Because, before the M1 chip Macbook used to suck under load due to a lack of fan and inadequate cooling, so as soon as you put the MacBook Air under any load the temperature shoots up and it thermal throttles and lowers its clock to cool down the CPU hence the low performance.

Answer (score 0):

If upgrading to the latest version is no use - try archive of lts versions.
https://unity3d.com/unity/qa/lts-releases

Maybe there're some 2015, 2017-ish versions, but this way you will miss all the newest features

Unity became more demanding for last couple of years, so downgrading might actually help here. But I wouldn't expect too much